# Multiple loops on one page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I need 3 different queries in one page.

When I do it I get an error like this:

**Cannot redeclare filter_where() (previously declared in W:\home\zerk\www\wp-content\themes\newss\most_commented.php:19) in W:\home\zerk\www\wp-content\themes\news\most_commented.php on line 41**

Here is my code:

```
<div id="page-wrap">

    <h3>Most commented </h3>

    <div id="example-five">

        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-one"><a href="#featured" class="current">Lat day</a></li>
            <li class="nav-two"><a href="#core">Lat week</a></li>
            <li class="nav-three"><a href="#jquerytuts">Lat month</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="list-wrap">

            <ul id="featured">

 <?php
  function filter_where($where = '') {
   $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days')) . "'";
   return $where;
  }
  add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
  query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC');
  while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
  <li>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php           the_title();     ?></a>
</li>
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>

            </ul>

             <ul id="core" class="hide">
<?php
function filter_where($where = '') {
 $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . "'";
 return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC');
while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title();     ?></a>
</li>
  <?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
             </ul>

             <ul id="jquerytuts" class="hide">
<?php
function filter_where($where = '') {
 $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
 return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC');
while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title();     ?></a>
</li>
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
             </ul>



</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is given in the error message very clearly.

**Cannot redeclare filter_where()**

You can't re-declare the function `filter_where` - try this. Notice the functions are given unique names.

- filter_where
- filter_where2
- filter_where3

This is true in all PHP, you can't have more than one function with the same name.

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <h3>Most commented </h3>
    <div id="example-five">
        <ul clas="nav">
            <li class="nav-one"><a href="#featured" class="current">Lat day</a></li>
            <li class="nav-two"><a href="#core">Lat week</a></li>
            <li class="nav-three"><a href="#jquerytuts">Lat month</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="list-wrap">
        <ul id="featured">
            <?php
                function filter_where($where = '') {
            $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days')) . "'";
                return $where;
            }
                add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
                query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC');
                while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php           the_title();     ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>

        </ul>

        <ul id="core" class="hide">
            <?php
                function filter_where2($where = '') {
            $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . "'";
                return $where;
            }
                add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where2');
                query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC');
                while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title();     ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
        </ul>

        <ul id="jquerytuts" class="hide">
            <?php
                function filter_where3($where = '') {
            $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
                return $where;
            }
                add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where3');
                query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC');
                while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title();     ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

That said, the code has lots of other problems too - I would suggest reading a basic introduction to PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

The whole idea of a function is one of encapsulation, that is, you write the code once - then call it when you need that functionality.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp

Comment: Thank you very much.I try this and there is no error, but there is no posts also. i can`t understand where is the problem. I have posts which have comments, but there is no output of the query.

Comment: Like I said, the code has lots of other problems - read about multiple loops in wordpress - http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops and http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/multiple-wordpress-loops